# How to do picture overlay in HTML (something like marker on top of google map)?

Tags: html, overlay, image

Anyone know how to do picture overlay or appear on top of each other in HTML? The effect will be something like the marker/icon appear on Google Map where the user can specify the coordinate of the second picture appear on the first picture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `<div>` containers to seperate content into multiple layers. Therefore the div containers have to be positioned absolutely and marked with a z-index. for instance:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:100">This is in background</div> 
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:5000">This is in foreground</div>
```

Of course the content also can contains images, etc.

Comment: When I do this everything is on top of everything.  I just want to overlap a h3 on top of an image.  It cannot be a background because it has an opacity.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DIV tag and CSS absolute positioning, with the z-index property.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html